# How can I detect closing window angular5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to delete some data when the user closes the page

I already used  `beforeunload` event but it work only when I refresh the page but when I close it nothing executes.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnloadHander($event) {
    console.log('fdfsdfsd')
    if(!this.accepted && this.details.length != 0){
      this.bookingService.deleteRequest(this.details[3]);
    }  
  }
```

if there's any other method can I use it
I'm using Angular 5

Comment: how do you try to close the page?

Comment: by close button in the navigator

Comment: i am not sure but i guess if you try to close the page via the browsers close buttons js will not notice that - does the event fire after clicking `x` at the tab?

Comment: try returning a string within the condition you need to make request

Comment: No doesn't work for me

Comment: Still looking for a citation but I'm fairly certain that you cannot make asynchronous network requests in a `beforeunload` (because closing the window would have to wait for the network request to complete, which would be a nice way for malicious actors to force a window to stay open.)